# QT/C++, OS X: Alternative for hide() when quiting app so that app keeps running and shows up again after clicking icon in dock

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I'm using QT with c++ on Mac OS X.
When closing my application I use **hide()** to keep my app running and to hide the window.

But afterwards when I click on the icon of my app in the **dock**, it does not show up anymore.

I read [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/2416) that using the following code instead of hide() should fix this behaviour:

```
ProcessSerialNumber pn;
GetFrontProcess (&pn);
ShowHideProcess(&pn,false);
```

But I don't know how to use that code :s
Can somebody explain how to use this code, or how to solve my problem?

thanks!

Comment: where did you read that? edit and add link.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/2416

Answer (score 2):

You can compile Objective-C inside your Qt app, so do the next:

Add this to your **.pro** file:

```
macx {

    LIBS += -framework Foundation
    LIBS += -framework AppKit

    OBJECTIVE_SOURCES += objectivec.mm
    HEADERS +=  objectivec.h
}
```

Create a file called **objective.h**:

```
#ifndef __ObjectiveC_h_
#define __ObjectiveC_h_


class ObjectiveC
{
public:
    static void HideWindow();
};

#endif
```

Another one called **objective.mm**:

```
#include "objectivec.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

void ObjectiveC::HideWindow()
{
    [NSApp hide:nil];
}
```

And then just use this wherever you like:

```
#ifdef Q_OS_MAC
   #include "objectivec.h"
#endif

#ifdef Q_OS_MAC
   ObjectiveC *obc = new ObjectiveC();
   obc->HideWindow();
#endif
```

Comment: I'm getting `:-1: error: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64` with this.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are talking about is native OSX API. I am in foreign territory but I am going to try to make magic here:

for `ProcessSerialNumber`

```
//either
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h> 
#include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
```

for `GetFrontProcess (&pn);`

[Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/Mac__Processes.3pm.html):

> The GetFrontProcess function returns the process serial number of the process running in the foreground.  Return "undef" if an error was detected.

Signature:

```
 //carbon or cocoa
 OSErr GetFrontProcess (ProcessSerialNumber *PSN);
```

for `ShowHideProcess(&pn,false);`

Signature:

```
 #include <Carbon/Processes.h> //carbon only?
 OSErr ShowHideProcess(const ProcessSerialNumber *psn, Boolean visible)
```

Comment: I think you are pretty close. Including Cocoa gives me >2000 errors: stray '@' in program. Including Carbon gives the error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64. Including carbon/processes.h returns that this header does not exist. Do you have more magic to try :) ?

Comment: I found an alternative: I can disable the dock icon and only use the systray icon. But still thanks alot for your magic @UmNyobe :p